# How to dock an element to another while respecting parent container size?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to layout two labels in a fixed width column.  One left-aligned and growing to the right, the other directly to the right of it.

When the combined width of the labels is smaller than the available space there should be empty space to the right.  This is achieved with this markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="Sample Name" />        
    <Label Content="Text" Foreground="#AAAAAA" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: First case, left label is short]

When the first label is too large, the text is trimmed and the label at the right should not be pushed out of the column.  This is achieved with this markup:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Label Content="Text" Foreground="#AAAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="A Really Really Long Sample Name" />        
</DockPanel>
```

[image: Second case, left label is too long]

How can I get the same results (the screenshots) without different pieces of Xaml?

Comment: i am sorry, but doesnt the second method cater both situations for you

Comment: Oops, I had the code samples mixed up.  The `Grid` method doesn't work when the name is long because it pushes the "Text" label out of the viewable area.  The `DockPanel` method doesn't work when the name is short because the "Text" label stays anchored to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something that I thought I had tried.  This did it for me:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="Sample Name" />
    <Label Content="Text" Foreground="#AAAAAA" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking then; this doesn't work.  The label stays on the right hand side rather than being close to the right hand side.